# MongoDB: aggregation with redact with $in fails

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got the following two `Objects` in a mongo collection named `cars`:

```
{vendor: "BMW",
model: "325i",
class: "coupe",
equipment: [
    {name: "airbag",
     cost: 120
    },
    {name: "led",
     cost: 170
    },
    {name: "abs",
     cost: 150
    }
 ]
}

{vendor: "Mercedes",
model: "C 250",
class: "coupe",
equipment: [
    {name: "airbag",
     cost: 180
    },
    {name: "esp",
     cost: 170
    },
    {name: "led",
     cost: 120
    }
 ]
}
```

I'm playing around with the new aggregation feature [redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) introduced in Mongo 2.6
I want to perform a query to get a list of cars with filtered equipment parts.
In words: Give me all cars of type coupe and only the information about `LED` and `AIRBAG` equipment.

I've tried this aggregations:

```
db.cars.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {"class": "coupe"}},
        {$redact:
        {
            $cond:
            {
                if: { $in : ["$name", ["airbag", "led"]]},
                then: "$$DESCEND",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
        }
    ]
)
```

But that leads to following error:

> assert: command failed: { "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator
>   '$in'", "code" : 15999, "ok" : 0 } : aggregate failed

What I'm doing wrong? Is there another way to achieve the goal.

I would expect to get back this result from Mongo:

```
{vendor: "BMW",
model: "325i",
class: "coupe",
equipment: [
    {name: "airbag",
     cost: 120
    },
    {name: "led",
     cost: 170
    }
 ]
}

{vendor: "Mercedes",
model: "C 250",
class: "coupe",
equipment: [
    {name: "airbag",
     cost: 180
    },
    {name: "led",
     cost: 120
    }
 ]
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Cheers,
Ralf

Comment: You want to use `$setIsSubset` instead of `$in` when performing aggregations (including redaction) in MongoDB.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset

Comment: You can use `$filter` with `$in` from 3.4 version. Something like `db.cars.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "class": "coupe",
      "equipment.name": {
        "$in": ["airbag", "led"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "equipment": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$equipment",
          "as": "equipment",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$equipment.name",
              ["airbag", "led"]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline operator is really not the one you want for this case. What it wants to do is recursively "descend" through the document structure and evaluate the conditions at each "level" to see what actions it is going to take.

In your case, there is no "name" field at the top level of the document in order to meet the condition, so as a result the whole document is "pruned".

You are after filtering arrays, and for that case where you do not want to use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), then you can use the new operators such as [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/):

```js
db.cars.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "class": "coupe" }},
    { "$project": {
        "equipment": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$equipment",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                             { "$or": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.name", "airbag" ] },
                                { "$eq": [ "$$el.name", "led" ] }
                             ]},
                             { "$cond": [ 1, "$$el", 0 ] },
                             false
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator works with the array and evaluates a logical condition against all of the elements, in this case within [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/). The same thing as **`$in`** which is not a logical operator in this sense is using [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/), which is a logical operator for the aggregation framework.

As any item that does not meet the condition would return `false`, what you need to do now is "remove" all of the `false` values. This is aided by [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) which will do this by comparison.

The result is what you want:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b2725120edfc7d0df2f0b1"),
    "equipment" : [
            {
                    "name" : "airbag",
                    "cost" : 120
            },
            {
                    "name" : "led",
                    "cost" : 170
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b2725120edfc7d0df2f0b2"),
    "equipment" : [
            {
                    "name" : "airbag",
                    "cost" : 180
            },
            {
                    "name" : "led",
                    "cost" : 120
            }
    ]
}
```

If you were really intent on using **`$redact`** then there is always this contrived example:

```js
db.cars.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "class": "coupe" }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$or": [
                    { "$eq": [
                       { "$ifNull": ["$name", "airbag"] },
                       "airbag"  
                    ]},
                    { "$eq": [
                       { "$ifNull": ["$name", "led"] },
                       "led"  
                    ]},
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$DESCEND",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

So that basically makes sure that if the field does not exist at all when descending then it will "artificially" produce one that is going to match, so that level does not get "pruned". Where the field does exist, the found value is used, and if that does not match the condition then it will be pruned.

Comment: @Ralf Glad to help. $redact is a hard thing for people to get their head around as a new concept. Either approach is valid, just depends on what syntax seems clearest in it's purpose to you and co-workers.